# About the center of an algebra over different fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is it true that the center of an algebra is bigger when the ground field has positive characteristic than the center of the same algebra over a field of characteristic zero? And why? Can someone explain it to me? (In both cases YES or NO)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by the center of the *same* algebra over a different base field?

Comment: Many thanks for your comment! I mean suppose we are given an algebra $A$ over a field $\mathbb F$ of positive characteristic. It has center $Z(A)$ over $\mathbb F$. Now let us change our field to $\mathbb K$ with characteristic zero. Now $A$ will have center  $Z(A)$ over $\mathbb K$. Now my question is that is it true that $|Z(A)|$ over   $\mathbb{F}    \ge | Z(A)|$   over 
  $\mathbb{K}$?

Comment: If $A$ is an $\mathbb{F}$-algebra, then it is an $\mathbb{F}$-vector space; if $A$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra, then it is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. It does not make sense to change from one to the other for the same $A$.

Comment: Nikita, you really need to specify how you *change the field*. One well-defined way of doing that is to assume that you have a ring $A$ that also happens to be a free $\Bbb{Z}$-module (when the integer multiples of $1_A$ are in the center). Then you can *extend the scalars to any field* $K$, that is, consider the algebra $A_K=A\otimes_{\Bbb{Z}}K$. Then you A) get a $K$-algebra related to the original ring $A$, B) and may be able to compare the centers of $A_K$, with $K$ varying, e.g. by comparing $C(A_K)$ and $C(A)\otimes K$.

Comment: But, then you change the algebra. Neither $A_{\Bbb{Q}}$ nor $A_{\Bbb{F}_p}$ is a subring of the other, so it is strictly impossible to compare their respective centers. We can meaningfully view $A_K$ as a subring of $A_L$, when $K\subset L$, but in that case  $K$ and $L$ necessarily have the same characteristic.

Answer (score 2):

An algebra $A$ over a field $F$ of positive characteristic *cannot* be an algebra over a field $K$ of characteristic $0$.

Being an algebra over $F$ means that there exists an *injective* ring homomorphism $F\to Z(A)$ (the center of $A$). In particular, if $p>0$ is the characteristic of $F$, then the $p$-element field $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a subring of $A$.

An algebra over a field $K$ with characteristic $0$ *cannot* have a subring with $p$ elements, because the minimal subring of $A$ is $\mathbb{Z}$.

A ring $A$ can be an algebra over different fields; for instance $F(x)$ (the ring of rational functions over the field $F$) is both an algebra over itself and an algebra over $F$. The center of $A$ doesn't depend on the field.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your question is not well posed.

First: What do you mean by "same" algebra? Ok, you could say that you are considering a quotient of a free algebra in a set of generators $X$ and ideal (of relations) $I$, i.e. $A=F\langle X \rangle / I$, but then you have to tell me how to carry them over to a field of positive characteristic. One way would be to consider the subring $R$ of $F$ generated by all coefficients of generators of $I$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ (assuming $char(F)=0$). So you might consider the ideal $I'$ in $R\langle X\rangle$, generated by the generators of $I$ and $A'=R\langle X\rangle/\langle I'\rangle$. Then cut down to characteristic $p$ by looking at $A''=A'/pA'$ and tensor it with your favourite field $K$ of characteristic $p$, i.e. $A'''=K\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_p} A''$.  Is this what you want?

Second: Comparing the cardinality is not a good choice. Simply consider the $2\times 2$-matrix ring $A=M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ over the rationals. Then $|Z(A)|=|\mathbb{Q}|=\aleph_0$ is countably infinite. However, if you look at $A'=M_2(K)$ for field of characteristic $p$ and $|K|=\aleph_1$, then certainly $\aleph_1=|Z(A')|>|Z(A)|=\aleph_0.$ Maybe you want to look at the dimension of the center over its base field?